# Why doesn't the construction of $\mathbb{N}$ through ordinals in ZFC violate Gödel's Incompleteness Theorem?

Tags: logic, set-theory, rational-numbers, incompleteness, natural-numbers

The title kind of says it all.  I've been working through   *Axiomatic Set Theory*, Suppes and *Mathematical Logic*, Kleene.  And I haven't thoroughly studied ordinals and incompleteness yet.  But, skimming through it I started thinking about this question.

In suppes, the set of natural numbers, $\omega$ is constructed using the ZFC axioms.  However, this seems like it goes against Gödel because ZFC set theory is a consistent theory.

---

Where is the discrepancy? Is there a limitation in the definition of $\omega$? Suppes later constructs the rational numbers out of the ordinals.  Do these rational numbers to satisfy the field axioms?

Comment: The incompleteness theorem doesn't say that no consistent theory can prove the consistency of PA; it says that no consistent theory $T$ at least as strong as PA can prove the consistency of $T$.

Comment: How do you know ZFC is a consistent theory?

Comment: Oh, I guess it was a false assumption.  I remember reading under the section of completeness of predicate logic, that if the set of axioms are simultaneously satisfiable then they are consistent (Kleene 320). I was assuming that that could have been done for ZFC

Comment: Can ZFC be shown to be consistent computationally through model theory by building a model that satisfies ZFC?

Comment: @BENG ZFC may well be consistent, but Godel's theorem implies if it is, we cannot prove this in ZFC. This includes the construction of a model of ZFC. Stronger set theories can construct a model of ZFC and thus prove consistency e.g. ZFC plus axiom of inaccessibles.

Comment: ZFC proves that PA is consistent. There's no problem with that, the Incompleteness theorem lets us infer that PA does *not* prove that ZFC is consistent (unless PA was inconsistent to begin with).

Comment: Your last paragraph doesn't make sense to me. Yes they satisfy the field axioms. But I don't see the connection that would imply we shouldn't care about incompleteness.

Comment: You haven't explained **why** you think the construction of the ordinals in ZFC "violates Gödel's incompleteness theorem".

Answer (score 4):

I suspect what you're thinking is something like:

> "Godel's incompleteness theorem says that we can't prove that PA is consistent. Yet ZFC lets us produce a model of PA, and so proves that PA is consistent. Isn't this a contradiction?"

The issue here is that when we say

> we can't prove that PA is consistent

we have to be very careful what we mean. Here are a couple of *true* statements:

- No consistent recursively axiomatizable theory extending (in any of a few different senses) PA can prove its own consistency.
- If PA proves "PA is consistent," then PA is inconsistent.
- If ZFC proves that PA is consistent and PA proves that ZFC is consistent, [then each is inconsistent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2076800/proofs-of-consistency-for-two-formal-systems).

The takeaway, essentially, should be "any theory proving the consistency of PA must be significantly stronger$^*$ than PA" - but that **doesn't** mean that no nice theory can prove the consistency of PA! ZFC proves the consistency of PA, is recursively axiomatizable and stronger (in an appropriate sense) than PA, and - as far as we know currently - is consistent (in particular, ZFC doesn't prove its own consistency).

Put another way, here's the right conclusion: since ZFC proves that PA is consistent, ZFC must be significantly more powerful than PA (and indeed, we know lots of ways in which it's *immensely* more powerful). In particular, when you write

> However, this seems like it goes against Gödel because ZFC set theory is a consistent theory

you're taking for granted the consistency of ZFC itself, which is even less trivial than the consistency of PA.

---

$^*$Making this fully precise is a bit subtle - ignore it for now.

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot.  I see know how incompleteness (ii) works with this question.  But I no have some confusion about the first part of incompleteness.  (To the best of my knowledge) it says that if a first order Theory $T$ that is (a) algorithmically denumerable (b) allows some of PA and (c) is consistent, then $T$ is not complete.  But completeness says any first order theory is complete.  Could you make the conclusion through contradiction that a theory $T$ that is both (a) and (b) is inconsistent?

Comment: @BENG: The completeness theorem states that first order logic is complete, as a logic, not that every theory is complete. That is demonstrably false.

Comment: @AsafKaragila. So there is a theory $T$ that is incomplete such that $T {\vDash} {\phi}$ and not $T {\vdash} {\phi}$?

Comment: @BENG: That is the completeness of *the logic*. A theory is complete if for every $\varphi$ either $T\vdash\varphi$ or $T\vdash\lnot\varphi$. It might be a good idea to review all the relevant definitions again, and not work from memory.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Hm, that definition of completeness of a theory wasn't given in the text I was working out of, (*Mathematical Logic*, Kleene).  I see that the same word is used to speak about two different things.

Comment: @BENG: Yes, "completeness" is quite ubiquitous in mathematics. Logic can be complete, a theory can be complete, a metric space can be complete...

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Thanks! Could I ask you for a text recommendation?  I've worked through pretty much all of Kleene, but there were a lot of things that it left out.  What would a good second pass of logic be?